# Add dynamic number of variables to WHERE clause in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following mySQL query:

```
SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score,  'vote' AS type
FROM votes
WHERE user_voter =  '1'
```

I want to be able to add and `user_voter` to the `WHERE` clause based on the result of another mySQL query. For example,

```
SELECT user_2
FROM friends
WHERE user_1 = '1'
```

This will output a dynamic amount of results based on the number of matches.

So, if the second query outputs:

```
3
4
11
32
```

Then I want the first query to be:

```
SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score,  'vote' AS type
FROM votes
WHERE user_voter =  '1' AND user_voter = '3' AND user_voter = '4' AND user_voter = '11' AND user_voter = '32'
```

Hope this makes sense!

Since I am using PHP I was thinking I might have to create a `while loop` and have it output the results as `"user_voter = '".$user2."' ";` and then append it to the `SELECT` query before running.

Comment: I think you want to use `OR` in your `WHERE` clause, not `AND`.

Comment: You could use `IN ()`. Just implode an array of numbers inside. -> `WHERE user_voter IN (3,4,11,32)` -- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in

Comment: @faint signal you are right, my mistake. @Sean this is exactly what I am after!  I guess I would just use `mysqli_fetch_array` to generate the array?

Comment: @matt1985 Instead of doing it in PHP, use a subquery, example posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a subquery inside an `IN()`

```
SELECT act_id, vote_date, vote_score,  'vote' AS type
FROM votes
WHERE user_voter IN (
                     SELECT user_2
                     FROM friends
                     WHERE user_1 = '1'
                    )
```